# Разработка под Android: существует ли "засор" проекта при постоянной модификации приложения?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Предположим, что мы создали проект в `Android studio` и начали разрабатывать приложение. В поцессе разработки мы, допустим, несколько тысяч раз создавали, модифицировали и удаляли различные файлы: Java-классы, xml-файлы и т. д. Будет ли процесс этой разработки сопровождаться накоплением всяких там временных файлов, служебных файлов и так далее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке проекта у вас на компьютере - да, естественно, среда разработки, git, gradle и т.д. будут, в процессе своей работы, создавать служебные папки и файлы.

В конечном билде (.apk) - нет, лишнего "мусора" туда не попадет, если сами не напихаете.